# What is the difference between putch() and putchar() in C Programming Language?

Tags: c

I have searched a lot on internet but I coudln't find any difference apart from the fact that both come from different libraries. So what exactly are the differences between `putch()` and `putchar()` in c?

Comment: putch() is non-standard.  Harks back to the early days of WindowsNT, back when it still had a posix sub-system.  It writes to the console without buffering and without paying attention to output redirection.  Odds you should use it are low.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

putchar(): This function is used to print one character on the screen, and this may be any character from C characterset(i.e it may be printable or non printable characters).

putch(): The putch() function is used to display all alphanumeric characters throught the standard output device like monitor. this function display single character at a time.

Answer (score 3):

`putchar` is a standard C function while `putch` is not. Otherwise they do almost similar job.